# update varchar with accent

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm doing a simple update that happens to have an accent in one of the letters:

```
update consultant   
    set nameConsultant = 'Laís Costa - Instituto'
    where ID = 77
```

But when I search this register with a select, this is the text that returned:

[image]

I read something about using COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS in the select but it didnt work.
Is there something in the update that I can put to make it work properly?

Comment: This wouldn't happen on its own. There's something else going on. Sounds like, perhaps, you are injecting this value from an application?

Comment: Don't store unicode chars in VARCHAR, unless you use UTF8. There's NVARCHAR for that stuff

Comment: What are the database and column collations?

Comment: If your database collation doesn't have `í` as a supported character I would expect it to be converted to a close equivalent or worst case `?`. The `Ã` looks like an issue with the application displaying the text. (UTF 8 corruption)

Comment: My guess is somewhere along the line, someone interpreted the UTF8 value `C3 AD` (the hex representation of the i-accent) as ANSI and then when it finally got passed to the database, it had been re-encoded as UTF-8, causing it to be treated as the a-squiggly. You can see the results in this [UTF-8 Tool](https://www.cogsci.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=%C3%AD&mode=char). TL;DR, it's likely a problem with the source system.

Comment: use N in the query to update : update consultant   
    set nameConsultant =N'Laís Costa - Instituto'
    where ID = 77

Comment: Normally I'd agree that character literals that could contain international characters should be National character literals, i.e.: `N'Laís Costa - Instituto'`, but if `í` already exists in the current database's default collation then it shouldn't make a difference. It seems like something else is going on here. How are you executing this update statement? Was this actually executed from an official Microsoft SSMS? Or have you written a custom process to load the statement from a file on disk and execute it against SQL Server? Does your process pay attention to the UTF-8 encoding of the file?